# emberjs in the console I see that records are created but they are not displayed by handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

First many **thanks to Mike Grassotti**, for helping in the IRC. He helped resolved the bugs with the save method.

My problem is that in the console I see that records are created but they are not displayed.

I am using ember-data to create new record. The **addComment function**  creates the **record in a transaction**, while the **save function**, only calls **this.transaction.commit**.

In the console after I click save(), the record seems created but handlebars doesn't display the newly created record. This is an excerpt of what I see in the console when I dig into the results of console.log

```
 >committed: Object
    firstRecordKind: "belongsTo"
    firstRecordName: "post"
 >firstRecordReference: Object
   clientId: 4
   id: "ember411"
>type: EmBlog.Comment
   ClassMixin: Ember.Mixin
  >FIXTURES: Array[1]
    0: Object
      body: "ty"
      id: "ember411"
      post: "1"
```

To create a new record, click on post -> then 'post title' -> at the bottom addComment- > then save and you will see that the record was not created.

**The relevant bit of code from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMkQ2/2/). This controller will not have a route as it will be sideloaded**

```
EmBlog.CommentNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

 needs: ['postsShow'],
 isAddingNew: false,

 addComment: function(body){
    console.log("this: ", this.toString());
    var post = this.get('controllers.postsShow.content');
    console.log(post);

   transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
   console.log(transaction);
   console.log(this.get('content').toString());

   this.set('content', transaction.createRecord(EmBlog.Comment, ({post: post })));
   this.transaction = transaction;

   console.log(this.get('content').toString());

   this.set('isAddingNew', true);
 },

 save: function(){
   var comment = this.get('content');

   comment.one('didCreate', this, function() {
      this.set('isAddingNew', false);
   });

  this.transaction.commit();

 }  

});
```

**The relevant bit from the handlebars template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/show">
  <h1>Post</h1>

  <h3> {{title}} </h3>
  <h3> {{body}} </h3>
   <br/>
  <p> {{#linkTo 'posts.index'}} back {{/linkTo}}</p>
  <p> {{#linkTo 'posts.edit' content}} Edit the post  {{/linkTo}}</p> 

  <br/>
  <b> Comments</b>
   {{render 'comment/new' comments}}
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='comment/new'>
     {{#if controller.isAddingNew}}
     <form {{action save on='submit'}}>
    {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="body" placeholder="body"}}
    <button type="submit"> save comment </button>  
    </form>
     {{/if}} 

    <br/>

   <div>
   <button {{action addComment}} {{bindAttr disabled="isAddingNew"}}>Add Comment</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, maybe i'm blind, but i can't see any code for displaying comments in your templates.

something like

```
<ul>
{{#each comment in comments}}
  <li>{{comment.body}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

should probably do the trick.

Comment: Thanks your are right. I skipped over that. It is displaying now.

Comment: For anyone interested, this is the **[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMkQ2/3/)**